# Pages taking too long to load after maven build

Tags: aem

I am using following command to deploy code to my AEM instance "mvn clean install -Daem.host=localhost -Daem.port=1202 -Dmaven.test.skip=true
"

After deployment pages are taking too long to load at least 7 mins.

I found No errors/Exceptions in error log.

Comment: Are OOTB geometrixx pages loading fine?

Comment: Same thing is happening with OOTB geometrixx.

Comment: So if you uninstall your code, again things turn back to normal is it? Is the disk space fine? Also check RAM usage of system, also in AEM `http://host:port/system/console/memoryusage`

Answer (score 1):

There could be couple of factors causing this slowness -

- Amount of memory allocated to AEM instance, default setting is - `CQ_JVM_OPTS='-server -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.awt.headless=true'` which is actually not sufficient for optimal performance. I have been using double of this configurations and sometimes even more.
- When you deploy your package with code, the bundles are processed and services are registered. Depending on number of services/components being registered the time can go up. Sometimes there are hooks within code that cause few system level bundles to cycle as well, if that happens it would actually cause all the other bundles dependent on system bundle to cycle and registering the services again.
- your code deployment could be triggering some workflow that either consumes lot of resources or is causing delayed activation on your bundle. The first scenario could happen if your deployment has something like images which when deployed causes OOTB image workflow to trigger (there could be other based on your code). Second scenario could be that you have bundle activator either waiting for another bundle which gets deployed later (and/or stays installed and not active) or you are building some sort of caching that waits for pages to be deployed and processed. There are countless such scenarios that can cause this issue.

What you could do is check the status of the bundles in /system/console/bundles pre and post deployment you can identify bundle related issues there. Another thing you could try is to do selective deployment of the code to figure out what module is causing issue that then dive deeper in to that module.

Also look at recent request logs to identify the flow of page load to see if there are services, filters etc in picture that are causing delays.

Let me know if any of this approach helps you identify the root cause and in case you need further help, will be here to assist.